# Accidentally deleted OS X via bootcamp

Tags: macos, mac, bootcamp, recovery

I accidentally deleted the OS X partition via Bootcamp. I tried to recover OS X via Internet Recovery (CMD + R), but it keeps getting stuck at the Globe all the time. I also created a bootable USB with Catalina, but as soon as I select it during startup, the Mac switches back to Internet Recovery and hangs. I have tried a lot of things, so I would like to turn to you and would be happy if someone would help me.

The things I've tried:

- Bootable USB created with Catalina = Does not run on Mac and switches to Internet Recovery
- Mac connected to mobile data = hangs at the globe
- Mac connected with 2.4ghz wifi and 8.8.8.8 DNS = Same problem
- Vram Reset = Same problem
- Different key combination tested (Shift+Option+Command+R) = Also switches directly to Internet Recovery and hangs.

As you can see, it always switches to Internet Recovery and hangs.

Comment: How did you delete OSX? What is the model/year of your Mac, version of Windows and version of OS X? Do you know if Windows was installed using the Boot Camp Assistant?

Comment: I accidentally deleted OSX because I wanted to expand the Windows partition, but I accidentally deleted the wrong partition. It's an iMac Pro Late 2017 with the latest OS X Catalina version I installed Windows with Bootcamp. Windows still starts normally when I start my Mac.

Comment: @asamass0 how did you solve this? I have done exactly the same thing as you. :(